# Create a File in a Protected Folder

Tags: java, file, directory, protected

I am attempting to create a folder (and a file inside of it) in a folder that is most likely protected.

Here's my code:

```
package me.pogostick29.audiorpg.data;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class DataManager {

    private DataManager() { }

    private static DataManager instance = new DataManager();

    public static DataManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private File folder;
    private File settings;

    public void setup() throws IOException {

        String foldername;
        String osname = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

        if (osname.startsWith("mac")) foldername = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support/AudioRPG";
        else if (osname.startsWith("linux")) foldername = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.AudioRPG/";
        else if (osname.startsWith("win")) foldername = System.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\.AudioRPG\\";
        else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown OS: " + osname);

        folder = new File(foldername);

        if (folder.exists()) {

            boolean success = false;

            try { success = folder.mkdirs(); }
            catch (SecurityException e) { FileUtils.forceMkdir(folder); }

            if (!success) throw new IOException("Could not create AudioRPG folder.");
        }

        settings = new File(folder, "settings.txt");

        if (!settings.exists()) {

            boolean success = false;

            try { success = settings.createNewFile(); }
            catch (SecurityException e) { throw new IOException("Could not create settings file."); }

            if (!success) throw new IOException("Could not create settings file.");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code (on a Mac), I get this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No such file or
>   directory     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native
>   Method)   at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)    at
>   me.pogostick29.audiorpg.data.DataManager.setup(DataManager.java:55)
>     at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.AudioRPG.main(AudioRPG.java:26)

How can I create a folder/file in this location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory();` to get the home directory. It works now!